# Can't access apache2 virtualhost from another computer

Tags: apache

I am running an apache2 webserver from my computer and when I access the site from my computer,
it works just fine, but when I try to access it from another machine(that runs windows), the browser outputs, that the site can't be reached.
Here is my site config file:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.96>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   puter
127.0.1.1   noreply.com
192.168.1.96    www.vk1.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I have tried restarting apache and disabling and enabling the site, but that didn't work.
Has anyone encountered such problems before?

Comment: What is in the log files? Does ping work? Maybe a firewall issue.

Comment: Is _other coputer_ in same network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/etc/hosts` file provides host to IP address mappings for the computer it lives on.

Your Windows computer is not going to read the data from your Linux computer's `/etc/hosts` file in order to know that it needs to make requests to `192.168.1.96` when it is asked to make a request to `www.vk1.com`.

You need to either:

- Configure that mapping in the DNS server for your LAN
- Put that information in the hosts file on the Windows computer

Comment: I have set up a redirect instruction in my site conf file and now I am getting "too many redirects" error instead of "non existent domain". The entry itself looks like this: Redirect / http://example.com/vkverify.html/

Comment: @kekula — That seems to be entirely unrelated to this answer or this question. If you have a new question [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (but you should probably [resolve this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) first).

Comment: Ok, I have resolved the question with nonexistent domain error, now I have to fix new bugs